# What are private extensions used for

Tags: kotlin

I came across the following code:

```
class BindableTextInputEditText : TextInputEditText {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    fun bind() {
        setTextAndCursor(text)
    }

    private fun TextInputEditText.setTextAndCursor(text: String?) {

    }
}
```

It isn't clear to me why setTextAndCursor is an extension. If it is private, it can't really be used generically like most extensions. So why make it an extension and not just a normal function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your *specific* case, the extension is declared in a class that extends the receiver class (`TextInputEditText`), so declaring a regular method would work the same way as an extension, or at least yield the same calling syntax. So I'd say it's pointless to use an extension here (some might mention performance of static methods here.. I wouldn't go down that road).

That being said, we can't *generally* dismiss private extensions. The point of an extension is not only generic usage, but rather a way to express static helpers in a more natural way using `object.method()` syntax.

This allows programmers to call similarly a built-in method and an extension method, which reads nicely. It can definitely be useful also in private contexts because the main goal is the nice syntax.

If `setTextAndCursor` is a method you would have liked to be on `TextInputEditText`, but it is only useful in your private context, then it makes sense to declare it as a private extension (except if you're already in a subclass of that class, which is your weird scenario).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "nice syntax". I personally don't see anything "nice" about it.

Comment: What I mean by "nice syntax" is calling `myObj.doSomething()` instead of the static equivalent: `doSomething(myObj)`. Depending on the semantics of the method, the former may be preferable in terms of style. Also, it may look nicer if you choose to chain the method call with other calls.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring it as an extension allows calling it on *any* `TextInputEditText`, not just on `this` (or other instances of `BindableTextInputEditText`). You could have a method like

```
fun bindOther(textField: TextInputEditText, text: String?) {
    textField.setTextAndCursor(text)
}
```

Maybe such a usage was in the class previously and was removed.